# Find tangent line of $f(x)=e^x+2$ that passes through origin

Tags: calculus

Defining the function:
$$f(x)=e^x+2$$
Find the point at which the line of the tangent passes through the origin.
I have found a graphical method and a numerical method of solving this, but no luck in solving it properly. I get stuck at trying to solve:
$$0=e^x+2.xe^x$$

Comment: Any line that passes through the origin has the formula $y=mx$. 

The tangent to $y=e^x+2$ at the point $x=a$ is $y-(e^a+2)=e^a(x-a)$.

Upon expansion, this is $y=e^ax +(e^a+2-ae^a)$.

Going back to how this line must take form $y=mx$, we deduce that $e^a+2-ae^a=0$. You've come this far. 

Unfortunately this does not yield a clean value of $a$, and would require the Lambert W function, but this is the farthest one can come.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent at $t$ can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
y = f'(t)(x-t) + f(t) = e^t(x-t) + e^t + 2.
\end{equation}
Now this should pass through the origin, hence we have
\begin{equation}
-t e^t + e^t + 2 = 0.
\end{equation}

In general, this does not have analytic solution, hence we need to solve this using some iterative numerical solution. I used a numerical method, which gives the answer: $1.4630555$.

There are hundreds of ways to solve this. Here's one method:
the following Python code will give the answer.

```
import scipy.optimize
from numpy import exp

def foo(x):
    return - x * exp(x) + exp(x) + 2

print(scipy.optimize.anderson(foo, 0.0))
```

You can solve the same problem using other methods in Python, or you can solve this using Matlab, too. (And there are still other methods!)

Comment: Yeah, I solved it numerically by using a Maclaurin expansion and got the same result (to some precision)

Comment: @LiKerren Awesome! Thought my code would help, but definitely, you already know how to do it. BTW, for this problem, we don't even need to depend on Newton-type-of-method. You can do even bisection to find the solution!

Comment: @LiKerren Probably my mindset is quite different, but I am machine learning scientist. If the problem gets bigger with multi-dimensional space, you're most likely not going to have analytic solutions. So, kind of depending on numerical solution may benefit you even when there exists analytic solution. But you may have different opinion on this. Just in case this may help you! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Given that the tangent line passes the origin, we have $f'(x) = \frac yx$, or

$$(x-1)e^{x-1}=\frac2e$$

Then, the solution is given by

$$x = W\left( \frac2e\right) + 1 $$

where $W(t)$ is the Lambert function. Thus, the tangent line is

$$y = \frac 2{W\left( \frac2e\right) }x$$

Comment: Interesting! The value of $W(2/e)$ should be calculated by numerical methods? like CDF of normal distribution? Or is there an analytic formula for it?

Comment: @SungheeYun - It is a special function, also known as the Omega function. So called, because it is common, yet with no elementary representation, much like other special function. You may evaluate in WA, e.g. W(2/e) = 1.436.

Comment: I see.. Thanks a lot for your teaching!